# Recursively calling a curried function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, currying, pointfree

As a toy example lets say we have this function and its usage:

```
const map = (f = n => n + 1) => (lst = [1,2,3]) => {
    if(lst.length === 0)
        return [];
    else
        return [f(...lst.splice(0,1)), ...map(f)(lst)];
}
const inc = n => n + 1;
const map_inc = map(inc);
map_inc([1,2,3]) // => (produces) [2,3,4]
```

Inside of the curried function map I am using "recursion" by calling `map(f)(lst)`.

The example above rebuilds the function before it can be called.

Is it possible to do this recursion without rebuilding the function?

I know of this way:

```
y = (f = (f, ...args) => [...args],
     ...args) => f(f, ...args);

const map = (mapper = n => n + 1) => (self = mapper, lst = [1,2,3]) => {
    if(lst.length === 0)
        return [];
    else
        return [mapper(...lst.splice(0,1)), ...self(self, lst)];
}
const inc = n => n + 1;
const map_inc = (...args) => y(map(inc), ...args);
map_inc([1,2,3]) // => (produces) [2,3,4]
```

I do not really like how this requires the passing of the function to itself.

Can this be done without the `y` function and without passing the function to itself? Can this be done in a more point-free style?

Comment: Your variable names make it very difficult to tell what you're trying to do. (I'm not the one who downvoted though)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: @NinoFiliu that may or may not be lodash's [`_.split()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#split). I have no idea until this question is improved.

Comment: What do you mean by *rebuilding the function*?

Comment: @NinoFiliu He means calling `reducer` again to get a new instance of the function it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can't return named arrow functions, but you can return a named regular function and call it recursively like this:

```
const reducer = k => function recurse(a, item) {
//...
    const s_res = _.split(item, k, 1);
    return recurse(a.withMutations(a => {
        a.push(s_res[0]);
        let a_element = document.createElement('a');
        a_element.setAttribute('href', '#');
        a_element.addEventListener('click', () => display_gen_element(k, obj));
        a.push(a_element);
    }), s_res[1]);
};
```

<sub>P.S. For the sake of readability please don't use one-letter variable names unless it's blindingly obvious what they're for, e.g. a counter in a `for` loop, etc.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose was remove the need to pass self to itself

`...self(self, lst)`

You can do this by adding 1 more function named `recursor`

```js
const map = (mapper = n => n + 1) => (lst = [1, 2, 3]) => {
  const recursor = lst => {
    if (lst.length === 0) return [];
    else return [mapper(...lst.splice(0, 1)), ...recursor(lst)];
  };
  return recursor(lst);
};
const inc = n => n + 1;
const map_inc = map(inc);
console.log(map_inc([1, 2, 3])); // => (produces) [2,3,4]
```

You didn't need the y combinator-like function called `y` at all.

`recursor` has `mapper` in its closure